# How can I get Lemon to define a terminal token in the file.h, without using that token in any reduce rule?

Tags: lemon

I have my lexical scanner implemented in Ragel, and I need a token to use when I recognize white-space of various sorts.  But other than separating other tokens, I don't care about the white-space.  If I pass it in to my Lemon parser, I'll have to insert many extra rules to get rid of it, which will make my grammar ugly and slow down parsing.  But the only way I've found to get Lemon to generate a token for white-space is to put in a reduce rule that I never intend to use.

Currently, I have a rule `list0 ::= .` to allow for an empty list, so I added a `list0 ::= SP.`.  Is there no cleaner way to just declare a token, without using it in a reduce rule?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Lemon specifically, but if your scanner recognizes white-space as tokens, your parser will probably want to as well. That is, you can't have white-space tokens in the input stream to the parser and have a clean parse unless those tokens are consumed by the grammar.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Well, I have a loop that calls the scanner, receives a token, then calls the parser with the token.  It's easy in that loop to just discard the white-space tokens.  But for another purpose, it may be useful to see the white-space, so I don't want the scanner to completely ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%nonassoc`, `%right`, or `%left` to reserve a terminal token.

```
%nonassoc SECRET_TOKEN .
program ::= .
```

will generate:

```
#define SECRET_TOKEN 1
```